# add touchscreen right click options unity

Tags: customization, tablet, touchscreen

I have Ubuntu unity on tablet and I know that a 2 finger click right clicks but on small areas like dock icons I can't do it. On Windows I could touch and hold for 2 seconds. How can I accomplish this on Ubuntu Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting under the accessibility to have right click work.  I am not sure why, but your right click will only work this way once you set it.  I have no clue why they cannot have both a long click and a right click at the same time, but that is how it is.  File a usability bug.